# Why should I NOT update to Mavericks?

Tags: macos

I'm not really looking for a single correct answer. I'm just looking for some input regarding the inevitable "gotchas" Apple seems to sneak into every major OS X release that screw over a select handful of people before they have time to resolve whatever feature or app got removed in any given release. I want to know about anything at all; I'm a developer, so even lower-level system tweaks and restrictions have an effect on me.

Comment: Some AppleScript seems to be a bit broken, it can bork your Python installation (as usual with OS X updates), and Mail is having a fun time: http://tidbits.com/article/14219 (Gmail) and http://blog.fastmail.fm/2013/10/26/mac-os-10-9-infinity-times-your-spam/ (FastMail)

Comment: I'm sure there's a good question in here that fits with our Q&A format, but questions that work well here **do** have a single correct answer. So this sounds more like an invitation to discussion than a question that has an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

You (or anyone else) should not upgrade if you don't have a good backup, a good idea how or why it will make your life easier and you don't have a list of software that you need to work so you can check at your workflow won't get ruined or at lease slowed / disrupted.

Comment: I think I'm downgrading back to ML. Sadly. iMovie HD is way too crashy under Mavericks, and I use it on a weekly basis. I have no interest in learning the bizarre workflow for the new, "improved" iMovie.

Comment: Is it possible for you to set up a partion with a 10.8 build on it and boot into that for iMovie when you need it

Comment: @DanielLawson I'm a big proponent of "if it's not broken..." and when something works for someone professionally, I'm extremely hesitant to recommend any change until it has time to bake, settle and prove itself as an improvement. Unfortunately iOS is harder to delay, but it's entirely feasible to avoid Mavericks for quite some time to come for people that would prefer to not have anything change.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik. Xcode 5 no longer supports gcc or llvm 4.2

I still need to maintain some apps for 10.6
With xcode 4.x and 10.8 osx I could do this ok because I just symlinked a 10.6 sdk and could still use gcc or llvm 4.2

But upgrading to 10.9 I also upgrade to its xcode 5 so I could use the 10.9 sdk

I found even with the 10.6 sdk there is no ggc and llv 4.2.
Clearly I did not pay attention to the press.

Luckily I still had a xcode 4.x app (using timemachine restore and keep both) that seems to run ok side by side with the xcode 5.